# Reference line date that depends on filter

Tags: tableau-api

I have a graph, where you select country and covid restriction. In the data source you can see start_date and end_date of a restriction in given country. How do you create a reference band that shows when the restriction lasted? (if never ended, show the starting date till the most recent date)
[image]

Comment: Can you please add a few rows of your data?

Comment: What does y axis represent?